# Can I install WebSocket Support in IIS in Production without downtime?

Tags: iis, websocket, windows-server-2012, windows-server

We didn't realize we were missing support for WebSockets in IIS in our production environment due to the Windows feature not being installed (Windows Server 2012).

Can we install the feature in our production environment without causing down time or the app pool on our web applications to recycle? What experience has anyone had installing features in Windows in production in general? Is there documentation somewhere that details what is safe or unsafe to do?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could set up an identical site on another server (with websocket), do your stuff and when it is ready, switch the URL to point at the new server.

Comment: @pookie We are in a kind of DevOps-y situation where the infrastructure team takes care of the servers and networking, but kind of leaves managing the server features, software, applications, app pools and IIS configuration up to the devs. I don't really have a way to quickly setup a new server, domain name, SSL cert, firewall rules and deployment target in the time before the next maintenance period tonight.

Comment: Hmm okay, well at the very least, you could try getting hold of a machine and turning on the websocket feature to see if it asks you to restart.

Comment: FYI, the docs do not mention that you need a restart. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support (but never trust MS documentation! Ever!).

Comment: @pookie Hah, thanks. I'm going to reach out to our managed RackSpace support to see if they have an answer and I'll post it here if I find it. Thanks for the link to the article.